# Why does numlock say it is on when it is actually off?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get a textbox to show the current state of the NumLock key. The first time I press the NumLock key, the textbox will show the correct state, but subsequent presses show it is still in that state. The code I have is below:

```
private void getNumlockState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numLock == true)
        {
            lblNumlock.Text = "Numlock On";
        }
        if (numLock == false)
        {
            lblNumlock.Text = "Numlock Off";
        }
    }
```

I am using a case statement to determine what key has been pressed:

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.NumLock:
                e.Handled = true;
                getNumlockState(sender, e);
                break;                
    case Keys.NumPad0:
                e.Handled = true;
                btnZero.PerformClick();
                break;
    case Keys.NumPad1:
                e.Handled = true;
                btnOne.PerformClick();
                break;
    // I have removed the case statements for most of the keys

    }
}
```

The Form load event handler:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;    
    }
```

Comment: What event are you listening to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you are always enabling the `numLock` for every `NumLock Key Press.`

**Solution :** for every `NumLock` Key `event` you should check Last `NumLock` status and do `inverse`.as you are displaying Key `ON` or `OFF` Status.

Try This:

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
case Keys.NumLock:
            if(numLock)
            numLock=false;
            else
            numLock=true;
            e.Handled = true;
            getNumlockState(sender, e);
            break;                
case Keys.NumPad0:
            e.Handled = true;
            btnZero.PerformClick();
            break;
case Keys.NumPad1:
            e.Handled = true;
            btnOne.PerformClick();
            break;
// I have removed the case statements for most of the keys


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not actually reading the state of the <kbd>Numlock</kbd> key, but trying to track it in your code instead, you need to actually toggle the value in your code:

```
case Keys.NumLock:
    e.Handled = true;
    getNumlockState(sender, e);
    numLock = !numLock;     // Invert (reverse) current value
    break;
```

Comment: the `numLock != numLock` is actually a boolean expression, it should be `numLock = !numLock`?

Comment: But I've just tried it in VS 2008 and there is an error, is it a new feature in next version of c#?

Comment: @KingKing: Yep. Old C/C++ syntax. Thanks for the catch.